# Adding a quantity to multiple indexes in an array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

So my problem is that I have a vending machine. The vending machine has slots with a max number of items per slot.

If I run the restock method with a product name and quantity, I need to add the quantity to the product supplied. I have a string array, and a stock array, for which the index is the slot number.

The problem is that if I have the same named product twice in the list, the first index of the product will reach the max, but the second instance of the product is always 1 less than I need it to be.

Ex. 
I have candies at slot 0 and 1 with a max of 10.
running restock(candies, 8) then restock(candies, 5) should provide 10 in slot 0 and 3 in slot 2. But instead I get 10 and 2.

```
public void restockProduct(String product, int quantity) {
    int index = -1;
    // If there is nothing to add, quit
    if (quantity == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        //Find location of product
        if (products[i].equals(product)) {
            index = i;
            if(stock[index] <= max)
            break;
        }
    }
    if(index >=0){
        stock[index]++;
        restockProduct(product, quantity-1);
    }
```

THanks

Comment: You shouldn't have two arrays. You should have a `Item` array, where `Item` is a class you write. Java is an OOP language, embrace it and you'll get self-documenting and easy to maintain code.

Comment: I agree, but I need to do it this way for a class

Answer (score 1):

It seems with this code and a `max` of 10 that you would get 11 in the first match and 2 in the second match, because of this line:

```
if(stock[index] <= max)
```

If the slot is already full, equal to `max`, then you are still choosing it for incrementing later.  Try strictly less than.  Additionally for clarity, combine the two `if` conditions.  You'll only want to choose the slot if the product name matches *and* it's not full.

```
if (products[i].equals(product) && stock[i] < max) {
     index = i;
     break;
}
```

You'll also have to handle the case when no slot matches both conditions.

Comment: I messed around with the conditionals quite a bit, as being off by 1 is usually an indication of bad conditionals. But doing this gives me 9 in slot 0, and 3 in slot 2.

Comment: Your off-by-one error must be elsewhere.  Mocking up your code produces values 10 and 3 with the `<` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking way too hard on this one

```
public void restockProduct(String product, int quantity) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) 
    {
        //Find location of product
        if (products[i].equals(product)) 
        {
            int diff = max = stock[i];
            stock[i] += diff;
            quantity -= diff;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THere has to be more to it than that. DOn't i need to take into account the quanitiy being <0 and stuff

Comment: @user2133337  that all depends on what the requirement is.  If you add negative quantities, it will do just that(subtract)